# How to setup system proxy for VS2015 when using Tools for Apache Cordova

Tags: visual-studio-cordova, taco

My question is how to setup system proxy in windows, because I got the following message from VS2015 output, and system proxy should setup in IE proxy setting. But it looks like need to setup in the other way. Any help on this?

> RUNMDAINSTALL : warning : The proxy currently configured for npm (http://proxy.domain.com:8080/) does not match the detected system proxy (http://proxy:8080/). This may result in package installation failures

Comment: The warning message shows conflict between proxy configs of npm and system. If you are using tools for apache cordova update 8 or later. We have an option to auto-apply the System-Level proxy to npm config. See NPM Proxy section of [New Features](https://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/release-update-8/#new-features).

Comment: @ElvisXia , thanks your reply. After I checked the box but no luck, I still got the same warning. But thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

From your description, I think you can ignore this warning if you didn't encounter any issue when build your Cordova app(or when install packages using npm). The proxy configured for npm is full qualified address against the system level one. If it is not a wrong address, I think it should work.

To change the npm proxy setting, you can follow the instructions(using npm config command) mentioned in To section "configure proxy settings for npm package manager" in [this article](http://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/configure-vs-tools-apache-cordova/).

If you want to change the system level proxy, I think you need to use netsh command as below:

```
netsh winhttp set proxy myproxy
```

Comment: thanks your reply, I think I'll ignore this warning, because it didn't encounter any issue for me. But if it could read from IE proxy setting would be better to setup it up, because chrome also use the same setting on windows.